# Chrome Dev Tool Shrinks screen when inspecting an element

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, inspect

I am creating a dev. site to eventually replace an existing site and every time I inspect an element the body of the page shrinks down to a third of the left half of the page. It is also happening randomly with the slider where the image shows on only half the page from time to time. If I refresh the page it corrects it until I inspect an element again. It is making it impossible to work on this site and I have disabled the theme and gone to a stock theme as well as one by one disabled plugins trying to figure out what is causing this glitch and I have yet to determine what could be causing this issue. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: perhaps you could include a screenshot.  It could be a css thing in your code, or perhaps one of the mobile views.  Does it do it if you undock dev tools to a different window?

Comment: it will not allow me to upload a screenshot but if you go to dev.resolvly.com and inspect an element you will see what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using chrome dev tools (assuming the dev-tools window opens separate from chrome, not in the same window) my guess is that your device toolbar may be toggled.

Click this to turn it off, as it's used to test your site on a different screen sizes and could be shrinking your screen whenever you inspect something.

[image: Device Toolbar in chrome dev tools]

Comment: No its not the emulator because it isnt shrinking the entire page it is just shrinking the body of the page. The header remains full screen.

Comment: With the link that you provided in the comment above, the issue can be reproduced without opening dev tools. The inspector doesn't have anything to do with it. If you resize the window to certain spots it will shrink the body. Giving `.grve-content {width:100%}` fixes the issue for me (;

Comment: I tried that and it is still doing the same thing at certain sizes as well as every time I inspect it.

Comment: I just deleted all of my custom CSS to see if it was something overriding something and it is still having the same issue. I am not sure what else could be causing this issue

Comment: Thank you. Your comment put me on the right track and I think I fixed it by adding #grve-content {width:100%}

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you have your Dev tools Emulator on which helps you emulate the web page in different device sizes. Try closing the emulator by clicking on it.
[image]

Comment: Its not the emulator. The header of the page remains full width, it is just the body of the page that shrinks to a third of the screen

Comment: Thanks for the link. Quickly scanning the site it looks like there is some logic that's possibly happening on window resize that affects the styling. Try inspecting the javascript files.