# Chrome Developer Tools Cut Off Page When Changing Screen Width

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

When inspecting my webpage and trying to resize the screen width for responsive designing it begins to cut my website on anything lower than about 1340px. See link for photo.[Screen Width In Chrome Developer Tools Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wflJW.png)

Comment: can you share the css for the responsive portion. are you using boostrap ?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-web-design-tips-bootstrap-css/

you'll need to specify the layout for the smaller screen size in the different containers.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: I'm using the grid system. It only happens when I inspect with the chrome developer tools. Otherwise resizing the browser window without dev tools open doesn't create that white space on the right side of the screen. I'm newer to web development but I don't want to get too far and it become an issue later on. I am just starting the media queries and adding them only has affect when resizing with the browser window. The white space on the right still appears when I inspect and resize with the developer tools...which I need to use to know my screen width.

Comment: https://codepen.io/saltyndead/pen/RwPyyMZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was one of my first websites and I actually ran into this same issue a couple years later during the front-end bootcamp I attended. As I was more experience by then it was easier to find the element causing the issue. If you're not sure what styling may be causing this, you can inspect in the dev tools, and in the elements tab you select a parent element and use the arrow keys (Right & Down) to navigate through the DOM. This will eventually highlight your trouble element's styling issue (You'll see it extending past the media query that everything else is adhering to) and you can fix it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
you need to create different styles for each resolutions
im not sure if you done it already but this should help you

in that's how i make my projects responsive

you may need to make a new background image with each new screen size but that is easy just download gimp and resize the image make sure that you resize it in a way that it doesn't stretch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357960/chrome-dev-tool-shrinks-screen-when-inspecting-an-element ... it looks like this guy had the same issue but not a clear answer to his fix